# Excel sequential dates with gaps

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

I am trying to create a backup for my timesheet in Excel because I work in several different departments. I need to do a run of seven dates, a space, run of another seven dates, followed by three spaces on repeat. These are all done in column and the empty spaces are empty rows. I want to be able to format this for the entire year. Below is an example. Thank you for any assistance.

```
1/1/2021
1/2/2021
1/3/2021
1/4/2021
1/5/2021
1/6/2021
1/7/2021
(empty row)
1/8/2021
1/9/2021
1/10/2021
1/11/2021
1/12/2021
1/13/2021
1/14/2021
(empty row)
(empty row)
(empty row)

1/15/2021
```

and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Put `1/1/2021` in A1

In A2 put:

```
=IF(OR(MOD(ROW($ZZ1),18)+1={8,16,17,18}),"",MAX($A$1:A1)+1)
```

And copy down.

[image]